# More uibarbutton items in single uitoolbar or navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbaritem

how to add 'more' uibarbutton items in single uitoolbar or navigation bar. for ex have a look at below image here barbutton items are hidding in right corner instead of it i just want to add more button like tabbar application.... any suggestions n samples url....[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the size of UBarButton item added in toolBar or in navigation bar. .

ToolBar having width 320px(same for navigation bar) so you need to design according to this width. Add buttons in toolBar must be in a limit if you have huge number of batton then why not you change the control.Use table view and on tapping of each row you can do that which you want.

Comment: here the toolbar and barbutton items are created dynamically, including tittles of barbutton item.

Comment: then you need to maintain hierarchy, you can't add at same label.thats why i am saying if it is possible then change your way to show the items.This way is not proper.